# unix - x windows/X11 question

Tags: java, x11-forwarding

I have a java GUI jar file that i need to launch at my unix terminal. My system admin says "X is already enabled via ssh". But when i type xterm it says

```
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: xterm:  DISPLAY is not set
```

I did some reading and it says i have to login using 
$ssh -X mylogin@xyz

So my question is:
1) What should i do next...i typed xterm again but the window does not launch
2) Suppose i get it working somehow. How can i launch my java GUI. (do i simply type the jar file name)?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are connecting from your own computer to some server running SSH. First off, you need to install an X11 server on your own machine if you don't have one already. The terminology here is confusing - if you're connecting to another machine by SSH, you're probably used to thinking of your own machine as the client and the remote one as the server. But in the case of X11, those roles are reversed.

Then, you'll need to start X11 on your own machine and within that, launch an `xterm`. *Then* from that xterm, you can run `ssh -X myserver.example.com` and once logged into that remote server, run `java -jar myapplication.jar` and it ought to work.

The specific mechanism for launching an X Server on your own machine varies by operating system. On Linux/FreeBSD/etc, you're probably running one already. On a Mac, X11 is available under Applications if you've installed the developer tools. On Windows you'll need something like [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)

Comment: Message that i get is                                                 X connection to localhost:12.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown)

Comment: Ok. putty does not have an X server built into it (nor should it :)). So you'll need to set up an X server like Xming or Cygwin on your Windows system.

Comment: putty does have X11 forwarding:http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-x-forwarding

Comment: ok i installed Cygwin and am using X11 enabled putty session to login to my unix cluster. But i get the following error:  X connection to localhost:11.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your unix terminal and do:

```
export DISPLAY=<ip_addr>:0
```

For e.g. I would do export DISPLAY=10.18.192.89:0.
The ip-address is of the machine where you want to see the GUI and that machine should have an Xterm client running.

Comment: That's not normally feasible under SSH in my experience. In particular, when firewalls come into the picture it's by no means guaranteed that the SSH-server/X11-client will be able to initiate a connection to the SSH-client/X11-server. Not to mention it's insecure. Tunneling is generally preferred.